# Can we run HttpClient many times in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpclient

Due to android [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) , The task can be executed only once.

I'm trying to run HttpClient in UI-Thread. But it allows for the only once. If I want to get another data from another link which is not yet run at the first start, how can I do it? Until I get all data when the app starts for the first time, it takes long time. Is there anyone who  knows how to solve this problem ?

Comment: This is very inefficient (HttpClient is initialized/constructed over and over again, every time you execute new AsyncTask), a better solution is to bind a service (initialize/construct httpClient only once here), and call the network method from that service whenever you need perform network operation in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running a network operation on main thread. Use async task to run network operations in background thread (do your http requests in a background thread).

Do your networking in an async task like this:

```
class WebRequestTask extends AsyncTask{


    protected void onPreExecute() {
    //show a progress dialog to the user or something
    }

    protected void doInBackground() {
        //Do your networking here
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        //do something with your 
       // response and dismiss the progress dialog
    }
  }

  new WebRequestTask().execute();
```

Here are some tutorials for you if you don't know how to use async tasks:

http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-developmentthreading-part-2-async-tasks/

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Here are the official docs from Google:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can call the async task multiple times whenever needed to perform the download tasks. You can pass parameters to the async task so that you can specify what data it should download (for example by passing a different url each time as a parameter to the async task). In this way, using a modular approach, you can call the same aync task multiple times with different parameters to download the data. The UI thread wont be blocked so the user experience will not be hindered and your code will be thread safe too.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the first link.

Answer (score 2):

You can do multiple operations in an AsyncTask

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void param...){
    downloadURL(myFirstUrl);
    downloadURL(mySecondUrl);
}
```

An AsyncTask can only be executed once. This means, if you create an instance of AsyncTask, you can only call `execute()` once. If you want to execute the AsyncTask again, create a new AsyncTask:

```
MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
myAsyncTask.execute(); //Will work
myAsyncTask.execute(); //Will not work, this is the second time
myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
myAsyncTask.execute(); //Will work, this is the first execution of a new AsyncTask.
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, lemme try it out.